# Use Powershell to delete Solr cores beginning with a prefix

Tags: powershell, solr, powershell-2.0, solr4

Is there a way to use Powershell 2.0 to automate deletion of Solr cores that begin with a given prefix? For example, I would like to delete all cores that begin with "some_prefix".  I am using Solr 4.10.1, and want to delete cores with the following API call:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=UNLOAD&deleteIndex=true&deleteInstanceDir=true&core=some_prefix_etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will work:

```
param ($prefix = $(throw "-prefix is required"))

$client = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient)
[xml]$coresXML = $client.DownloadString("http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores")
$cores = $coresXML.response.lst[2].lst | % {$_.name}
$success = 0
$error = 0

foreach ($core in $cores) {
  if ($core.StartsWith($prefix)) {
    $url = "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=UNLOAD&deleteIndex=true&deleteInstanceDir=true&core=$core"
    write-host "Deleting $core :"
    $client.DownloadString($url)
    if ($?) {$success++}
    else $error++
  }
}
write-host "Deleted $success cores.  Had $error errors."
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937074/get-solr-cores-via-powershell) on how the syntax to extract cores to a list works, and [this](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#UNLOAD) on the Solr UNLOAD API options for deleting a core.